# How to plot the dataframe in form of matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, matrix

I have a dataframes containing few columns, however I already calculated the value of it,
df:

```
    age     size    gender   time
 1  0.0     3.433    3.454    2.165
 2  3.654   0.0      5.0      4.88
 3  6.43    1.33     0.0      3.56
 4  2.33    8.3      1.2      0.0
```

These are calculated values, so how can i show or plot it in the form of matrix such that:
Expected output:

```
      age     size    gender   time
age   0.0     3.654   6.43    2.33
size  3.433    0.0    1.33    8.3
gender 3.454   5.0    0.0     1.2
time   2.165   4.88   3.56    0.0,
```

I tried transpose but it didnot work, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `rename` the index then `transpose` the data:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True).rename(index=dict(enumerate(df.columns))).T


          age   size    gender  time
age     0.000   3.654   6.43    2.33
size    3.433   0.000   1.33    8.30
gender  3.454   5.000   0.00    1.20
time    2.165   4.880   3.56    0.00
```